# Grant user permission to create new schema but not view existing schema

Tags: mysql, sql, privileges

Is there a way to allow the user to create **new** schemas (and acquire privileges to schemas he created), but not view existing schemas (a way to blacklist a list of schemas that the user is not able to see works too)?

The `CREATE` privilege will allow the user to create **new** schemas, as well as viewing all the existing schemas (though not altering them).

Comment: revoke the select permission

Comment: I'd say that this is really a dba question

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal `SELECT` privilege was never granted. `CREATE` privilege alone gave view access to existing schemas.